# Get only 5 star rated reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

I am trying to get all the reviews for current product detail page which are 5 star rated.How are  we suppose to  filter ?

```
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $_product = $this->product();
             $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($_product->getId());
```

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();

$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();

    $summaryData = $reviews->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addEntityFilter('product', $_product->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
    ->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes();

foreach($summaryData as $child){

    $_votes = $child->getRatingVotes();

    if (count($_votes)){

        foreach ($_votes as $_vote){
            if($_vote->getPercent() == 100){
                echo $child->getData('review_id'); 
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Using above code you can filter 5star review.

Comment: ur code is returning me all the reviews of that product irrespective of their rating

Comment: Its filtering collection which have 5 star by if($_vote->getPercent() == 100){ . Are you using star on review?

Comment: yes i do i have 2 reviews with 4 stars i.e 80 and 1 with 3 star i.e 60. I used with   if($_vote->getPercent() == 80). It returned me all 3 reviews id.

Comment: Update code try with it